# Finding a word with an escaped apostrophe in a string using strpos

Tags: php, escaping, strpos, apostrophe

I have a word with an escaped apostrophe in a string. I'm trying to use strpos to determine whether the word with the escaped apostrophe is in the string or not. Unfortunately, it echoes false every time. What am I doing wrong? I have tried, in strpos, with 1 escaped slash, 2 escaped slash, all the way up to 5, but it's echoing false every time.

```
$text = "example\'s";
$text = " ".$text." ";

if (strpos($text, " example\\\\\'s ")) {
echo "true.";
}

else {
echo "false.";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here - the first is in your escaping of the string, and the second is in your logic based on the return from the `strpos` function.

The first problem is that you don't need to escape the search input to `strpos` - it's not a regex function!

The second problem is that your (unescaped) search string would match at position zero, which PHP also interprets as a false value.

The PHP [strpos docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) state:

> Warning
>   This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Use this code instead which should work fine:

```
$text = "example\'s";
$text = " ".$text." ";

if (strpos($text, " example\'s ") === false) {
    echo "false.";
} else {
    echo "true.";
}
```

The `===` operator is the key here - it means equal value and type, so it prevents the PHP interpreter from treating a zero return as equal to false, which it otherwise would do.

See PHP's comparison operators reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

**Edit:** Further info on the values PHP considers to be false: -

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> the boolean FALSE itself
>
> the integer 0 (zero)
>
> the float 0.0 (zero)
>
> the empty string, and the string "0"
>
> an array with zero elements
>
> an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
>
> the special type NULL (including unset variables)
>
> SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).
>
> Warning: -1 is considered TRUE, like any other non-zero (whether negative or positive) number!

From: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: It's still echoing false.

Comment: I just updated my answer - you shouldn't need to escape the string for `strpos` at all. Can you try it again?

Comment: btw, is 0 the only value it would interpret as false using ==?

Comment: Nope, there are lots of others! I've updated my answer further, and given a link to the relevant PHP docs. Thanks for the accept!